# Error when using ipapi python API for getting geo location from IP

Tags: json, python-3.x, ip

I am using ipapi to get geo location from IP. It works for most part but get the following error for some of the ip's I tried.

```
    File " ...ipapi\ipapi.py", line 47, in location
    return response.json()
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
*** print_exc:
  File "...\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**CODE:**

```
(ip.location(ip=ip_address))
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this issue??

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. Is your code in a `.py` file? and is that one line your entire code? what import statements did you use? etc.

Comment: Yes, the last line is from my code.

Comment: Ok, but your code works for me. You should provide more code, or more information about what  code you have in line `line 47, in location
    return response.json()`